# download scowl in Lunix using command line

Tags: scala, shell, ubuntu, ontology, owl-api

I have to manipulate my OWL file with Scala language. therefore, I found that scowl: `https://github.com/phenoscape/scowl` facilitates this task. I'm working with Lunix and Virtual Machine.

my questions are:

how to download scowl in Lunix with command line?

how to upload my owl file from github in Lunix?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can I ask what is Lunix? I am not familiar with either owl or scowl, but downloading files from internet can be achieved by `wget` command in POSIX compliant environment. If it is git repository, `git clone` should do.

Comment: Do you mean Linux?

Comment: About downloading/uploading files with owl api, it's transparent - OWLOntologyManager methods to load and save ontologies take IRIs as input, which can be GitHub URLs. Uploading will require your code to have the required privileges to write to GitHub though. Otherwise you can make your changes to a local file and upload separately, e.g., as part of a git commit.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of Scowl. It is meant to be used as a library in your Scala application. So you would add it as a dependency in your build file, whether you are using SBT or Maven or something else. It's available from Maven Central, and instructions are in the Scowl readme. I'm not sure what you mean by uploading your OWL file. Scowl provides a domain-specific language in Scala to allow you to manipulate OWL axioms in a readable way.